# Differentiate between first time data load vs filtered data load in Slick Grid

Tags: angular, slickgrid

I am using Slick Grid for rendering data. The same data gets displayed on Map. I am populating data in Slick Grid using following code.

```
 this.dataViewObj.beginUpdate();
 if (items && items.length > 0) {
      this.dataViewObj.setItems(items, ["id"]);
 }
 this.dataViewObj.endUpdate();
 this.dataViewObj.refresh();

 this.angularGrid.slickGrid.render();
 this.angularGrid.gridService.renderGrid();
```

While on Map I am rendering data in "onRowCountChanged" event of DataView Object.

```
this.dataViewObj.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
   /**
   * iterate over data in data view object and create an array of pointData 
   */
   dataSharingService.notifyMapToRenderPoints.emit(pointData)
})
```

Now the problem is "onRowCountChanged" function gets called when data is rendered first time in the grid as well as every time a filter gets applied to the grid.

I want to distinguish between first time data load and filtered data load in grid because for the first time I want to draw points on map and every time when filter is applied, the same set of points should be made visible/invisible based on the data seen in the grid.

How to distinguish between first time data load and filtered data load in Slick Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just declare

```
var dataHasLoaded = false;
```

somewhere, and use that to make a decision, eg:

```
this.dataViewObj.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  if (dataHasLoaded) {
    refreshBehaviour();
  } else {
    dataLoadBehaviour();
    dataHasLoaded = true;
  } 
})
```

You could also set

```
dataHasLoaded = false;
```

elsewhere in code if you want to load data again.